How do you transpile a Qiskit VQC for IBM hardware?
I have a VQC that runs fine locally (jupyter lab), until I expand the complexity (more variables) at which point it runs for about 10 mins then the kernel dies. So, I've tried moving it to the IBM Quantum Platform, but am getting the error:
"The instruction h on qubits (0,) is not supported by the target system. Circuits that do not match the target hardware definition are no longer supported after March 4, 2024. See the transpilation documentation (https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/guides/transpile) for instructions to transform circuits and the primitive examples (https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/guides/primitives-examples) to see this coupled with operator transformations."
I thought the transpile would happen automatically if the VQC is setup correctly, but that doesn't seem to be the case (or I'm doing something wrong).
My basic code:
from qiskit_machine_learning.algorithms.classifiers import VQC
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService, SamplerV2 as Sampler
from qiskit.circuit.library import z_feature_map
from qiskit.compiler import transpile

service = QiskitRuntimeService()
backend = service.least_busy(operational=True, simulator=False)
 
sampler = Sampler(backend)

feature_map = z_feature_map(feature_dimension=16, reps=1)
ansatz = RealAmplitudes(num_qubits=16, reps=3)
optimizer = COBYLA(maxiter=100)

vqc = VQC(
    sampler=sampler,
    feature_map=feature_map,
    ansatz=ansatz,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    callback=callback_graph
)

vqc.fit(x_train, np_y_train)

I've tried forcing a transpile, but can't figure out how to do so on an ML algorithm. I've searched for a few hours on this, and just can't find any good documentation that isn't depreciated, or only explains how to do this for a circuit.
All qiskit packages are pip --upgraded.

I don't think it matters if it's an ML algorithm. ansatz is a circuit and you can transpile it.
